# What is delta-v calculated in reference to?

Tags: delta-v

I understand delta-v is literally just the potential change in velocity, but this would obviously differ between air resistance, gravity and many other factors, so what is delta-v calculated in reference to? Does it assume 0 gravity and air resistance?

Comment: Have you tried to check the corresponding wikipedia page, or tried to compute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It assumes no gravity and no air resistance. For ascent from Earth's surface to LEO, it's typical to expend around 9.4 km/s of ∆v, to reach a final orbital speed of around 7.8 km/s.

Most of the loss, around 1400-1500 m/s, is in fighting gravity, with around 100-200 m/s lost to air drag -- the exact numbers vary with the characteristics of the launch vehicle.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't assume anything about your environment, but rather simply indicates what your engines can do.  If gravity is a factor some of your delta-v is used to counter gravity rather than actually accelerating your rocket.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to clear up the confusion on "is gravity/air resistance included?"

Say you've got an engine in free fall in the atmosphere. You're going 200m/s now and you'll be going 600m/s when you hit the ground ~40 seconds later. Your engine has 600m/s of delta-v which can be imparted over X seconds with a certain [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse).

*Note: I'll be assuming mass-less fuel for the simplification of these calculations using [System-specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System-specific_impulse) with a constant mass.*

---

If you want to stop before you hit the ground, you have 40 seconds in which the following will be happening:

- The engine will be **decelerating you**.
- The gravity from earth will be **accelerating you**.
- The air resistance will be **decelerating you**.

If, in 40 seconds, you've gained 400m/s and are at the ground, that means that the total sum of the forces of gravity and air resistance caused you to gain 400 m/s in total velocity as you fell. This means, that over that 40 second interval you will need to counter-act these forces that have been added to your velocity vector.

Lets say that your engine has a maximum impulse of 9.8 delta-v per second. Unfortunate, because that's exactly enough to counter-act gravity at maximal thrust, if you did a full-on burn for 40 seconds you'd hit the ground at close to 200 m/s because you [used 400m/s of your delta-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) to **counter-act the acceleration of gravity which was added to your velocity vector.** You didn't get to use any of your delta-v to negate your initial velocity because you didn't have enough time. You would, however, hit the ground with **200 m/s of unused delta-v left inside of your craft**, well, as it explodes.

If you wanted to hit the ground, perfectly at 0m/s you'd need a bare-minimum change in velocity of 15m/s per second to both counter-act gravity and remove your initial velocity. I think the main confusion you're having is delta-v and delta-v over time, which is acceleration. Gravity/drag are things that cause change in velocity over time. Delta-v is the total change in velocity your vessel is capable of, agnostic of time; [actual thrust calculations are needed to understand how fast you can apply this change in velocity as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)).

*Note: things get much more complicated [when your mass is changing over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) as well; these calculations are a gross over-simplification because they assume mass-less fuel and a constant engine/fuel mass. The efficiencies and limitations of fuels are based on something called [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse).*

In other words delta-v is simply how much **change in velocity** your rocket is capable of, it is **agnostic of all other forces which are acting upon your rocket** and is **usually used to counter-act external forces to achieve a desired velocity vector**.

Comment: Once again, if I've misspoke even on terminology here someone please correct me.